# Android app to wake up with the Sun

Tags: android, alarm-clock

I am looking for an alarm clock app for Android that sets the alarm according to the sunrise of my current location.

Comment: I've not tried any of those, but a [quick check for "sunrise alarm](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=sunrise+alarm) turns up 200+ results on AppBrain. Have you checked any of them? Besides, your question lacks some details: What's your price limit? Anything else you need (like different alarm sounds to chose from, ability to use "any MP3" for that, snooze, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Sunrise Alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fifthelement.sunrisealarm)? Seems to be doing just what you need.